# installing and building Go

Tags: go, git-bash

after installing go and setting the GOPATH value while trying to execute a file present in bin(hello.exe) as %GOPATH%\bin\hello,the error shows bash:fg: no such job(used gitbash)

Comment: If you build it to `exe` - why don't you run it directly?

Comment: you need to add $GOPATH/bin to your system PATH

Comment: I've already set the Path variable to my current working directory

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is due to the way you're referencing the GOPATH. In Bash (and every shell I've used), variables are accessed by preceding the variable name with a dollar ($) symbol, like so:

```
echo $GOPATH
```

so what you should be using to run your program is:

```
$GOPATH/bin/hello
```

(Note: in Bash paths are separated with forward slashes, rather than the back slashes used in Windows)

### An explanation of the error message

In bash and other shells, the percentage (%) symbol is used to reference stopped jobs. For example, we could do:

```
vim
```

(vim opens)

pressing ctrl + z will then send a stop signal to vim and return you to the shell. typing
    jobs
will then give you a list of stopped jobs:

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 vim  (wd: ~)
```

you can then re-start the job, bringing it back to the foreground using

```
%1
```

or

```
fg %1
```

(one being the number of the stopped job),